# System.data assembly in .netcore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to connect to HANA Database in my .net core application. I have added the Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5 assembly as a reference. However, when I execute the command:

```
HanaConnection conn = new HanaConnection("jdbc:sap://###;UserID=###Password=##;");
conn.Open();
```

I am getting an error that the DbConnection is not referenced.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0012  The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I tried to add the **System.data.common**, However, the 4.0.0 is not compatible with the .net core. Please can you help?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ".net core"? what *exactly* are you targeting? as an example, "dapper" targets "netstandard1.3" (in addition to some .NET Framework targets), and has a `<PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />` which works fine. Note: System.Data.Common 4.0.0 was released in July 2015; .NET Core wasn't a thing then - you'll need *at least* 4.1.0, but 4.3.0 would be preferable

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I say .net core, it means that when I created a new project, I selected .net core web application in VS 2017 as against the framework. The DB dll uses the older version and requires it to be added in the reference.

Comment: What is the "DB dll" here? If it is targeting System.Data.Common 4.0.0 then it isn't targeting dnxcore/netstandard/netcoreapp, because there is no System.Data.Common 4.0.0 that targets those platforms. You can still use the .net core *project system* to target .net framework (and not dnxcore, netcoreapp or netstandard) - and indeed I kinda prefer the new project system even for .NET Framework - but you'll need to edit the csproj and change the `<TargetFramework>` to `net46` or similar

Comment: But you might find it easier to just create a .NET Framework project, if you're not familiar with dealing with .net core and the new project system